# pandas duplicated() returning column values in one case and index values in another

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have two csv files, and I load that data into two different data frames:

```
CGMData_DF = pd.read_csv("./CGMData.csv", index_col=False, usecols=["Index","Date", "Time", "Sensor Glucose (mg/dL)"])
InsulinData_DF = pd.read_csv("./InsulinData.csv", index_col=False, usecols=["Index","Date","Time","Alarm"])
```

I want to check duplicates in column named "Index" in both the data frames

so for the CGM data I do this:

```
duplicateCGMindexes = CGMData_DF.duplicated(subset=["Index"])
duplicateCGMindexes[duplicateCGMindexes == True]
```

Jupyter notebook returns:

```
24628    True
24629    True
24630    True
24631    True
24632    True
         ... 
47545    True
47546    True
47547    True
47548    True
47549    True
Length: 22838, dtype: bool
```

I take the first value and check using this:

```
CGMData_DF.loc[CGMData_DF['Index'] == 24628]
```

and sure enough, Jupyter notebook tells me that there are two rows:

```
        Index   Date        Time        Sensor Glucose (mg/dL)
4273    24628   1/28/2018   16:17:34    NaN
27111   24628   10/31/2017  21:08:59    261.0
```

I repeat the same process for the Insulin data frame

```
duplicateInsulinIndexes = InsulinData_DF.duplicated(subset=["Index"])
duplicateInsulinIndexes[duplicateInsulinIndexes == True]
```

Jupyter notebook returns:

```
19295    True
19296    True
19297    True
19298    True
19299    True
         ... 
38585    True
38586    True
38587    True
38588    True
38589    True
Length: 19295, dtype: bool
```

I take the first value and check using this:

```
InsulinData_DF.loc[InsulinData_DF['Index'] == 19295]
```

Jupyter notebook returns:

```
        Index   Date        Time        Alarm
38590   19295   8/15/2017   22:24:13    NaN
```

Upon inspection I realize that 19295 is not the column value that is duplicated, but the row label of the column value that was duplicated

I get the "Index" column value for row label 19295:

```
InsulinData_DF.loc[19295]
```

Jupyter return:

```
Index            0
Date     11/9/2017
Time      12:23:04
Alarm          NaN
Name: 19295, dtype: object
```

I check for "Index" column value 0

```
InsulinData_DF.loc[InsulinData_DF['Index'] == 0]
```

and Jupyter return 2 rows:

```
        Index   Date        Time        Alarm
0       0       2/12/2018   13:20:53    NaN
19295   0       11/9/2017   12:23:04    NaN
```

My question is Why did `.duplicated()` function returned column values in one case and it returned row label in another case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I realized that the

```
duplicateCGMindexes = CGMData_DF.duplicated(subset=["Index"])
duplicateCGMindexes[duplicateCGMindexes == True]
```

was infact returning row labels only, I mistook them for column values

```
CGMData_DF.loc[24628]
```

gave:

```
Index                         22145
Date                      11/9/2017
Time                       12:24:33
Sensor Glucose (mg/dL)          117
Name: 24628, dtype: object
```

and

```
CGMData_DF.loc[CGMData_DF['Index'] == 22145]
```

gave:

```
        Index   Date        Time        Sensor Glucose (mg/dL)
1790    22145   2/6/2018    7:25:54     198.0
24628   22145   11/9/2017   12:24:33    117.0
```

infact column value 22145 was the first instance when the values again start repeating

Answer (score 0):

When you remove it check to assign it back

```
uniqueDF = InsulinData_DF[duplicateInsulinIndexes]
```